# JaCoCo not ignoring class

Tags: maven, unit-testing, jacoco, cobertura, jacoco-maven-plugin

I've successfully added JaCoCo to my project, it works fine, but for some reason it's not letting me excluding a class: **src/main/java/com/example/Main.java**

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>com/example/Main.*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.80</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.60</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I've tried the rest of questions in the site, but none of them worked for me when it comes to excluding **a single class**. After executing the code above, I get the following output, containing the class **Main**, which is the one I'd like to avoid:

[image: Output]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question the `excludes` block is declared inside `configuration/rules`. It should be declared inside `configuration`.

For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/Main.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I would suggest starting with the simplest possible plugin definition (i.e. what I have posted above) and once that's working extend it to (1) reference the class by package name and (2) to add your rules.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer buddy, I've tried it but didn't work though, could you please post the whole example?

Comment: To be precise: you're no obligated to specify `excludes` inside `plugin/configuration`, it obeys standard Maven principles, i.e. when specified in `plugin/executions/execution` applies only on the goals within this `execution`, when specified inside `plugin/configuration` applies on all executions, thus in particular can be specified in execution that contains `report` goal.